# edittext android add style programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have style:

```
<style name="editTextInput">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:digits">0123456780.</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">numberDecimal</item>

    </style>
```

I want add this style to my EditText. like this:

```
TableRow tableRowEdit = new TableRow(context);
EditText editText = new EditText(context, null, R.style.editTextInput);
tableRowEdit.addView(editText);
```

In layout XML this style work fine:

```
<TableRow style="@style/tableRowInput" >

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvTitleStyle"
                        android:text="@string/diameterSmall" />

                    <TextView style="@style/separatorInput" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/diameterSmallValue"
                        style="@style/editTextInput" />
                </TableRow>
```

but in programmatically dont'work.

Answer (score 0):

```
try below code

XmlPullParser parser = getApplicationContext().getResources().getXml(R.style.editTextInput);
AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
EditText editText = new EditText(context,attributes );
tableRowEdit.addView(editText);
```

Comment: I have error:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo ... android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060008